# SETOOL Kit:Error: "Unable to Clone the site. Check your network connection"

Tags: phishing, kali-linux

I have to tried to check whether a site is vulnerable to Phishing attack or not using "Setool kit" in Kali Linux. But when I tried to clone a site using this Setool Kit in Kali Linux, I got an error like:

> "Unable to clone the specific site. Check for network connection"

But I am able to browse in my browser, which means that I have Internet connection.

Does that mean that the site is secured against "Phishing attack" or is there a problem with my approach??

Comment: Same problem with me I restart my virtual machine then tried again and It worked.
please restart your machine.

Answer (score 2):

First off, a site can't really be vulnerable to a phishing attack. A site / email / app can always be duplicated convincingly from an aesthetic standpoint given enough time. So really, it would be the end user who is or isn't vulnerable to phishing since they are your target.

Regarding SET, the relevant logic in SET can be found [here (lines 130-167)](https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit/blob/07577ff538b97ff06c4d4ad3dbeb68d1cd3d9a8a/src/webattack/web_clone/cloner.py). Have you tried using `wget` to access the site? Specifically the command used by SET:

`wget --no-check-certificate -O index.html -c -k (-U [useragent]) [url]`

I parenthesized the useragent parameter as it probably isn't needed if you are running this from command line on the same computer as you are running SET. Otherwise it may be a permissions issue regarding SET not being able to write to disc. Make sure that you're running SET with `sudo`. Also perhaps try a site like google (**DO NOT ACTUALLY PHISH ANYONES GOOGLE ACCOUNT INFO**) that should work just as a sanity check.